# Writing Comments (metadata) within image file using R

Tags: r, png, metadata

I would like to add parameter information to the plots that we make as part of our research project.  I know that png has a text block for adding comments.  (I am not a png expert, but I think it uses the tEXt block.)  Using Gimp, under image properties, you can add a comment that can be read by other software (e.g. by the "inspector" in mac preview.  I'm sure there is a windows equivalent).  We make our images with ggsave.  I did not see any arguments to ggsave that allows us to write to the "comment" block of a png file.  I've tried using png::readPNG, and png::writePNG functions

```
im <- readPNG("test1.png",native=FALSE,info=TRUE)
md <- c(comment=paste0(date=date(),machine=Sys.info()['nodename']))
writePNG(image=im,target="test1_md1.png",text=md,metadata = md)
im2 <- readPNG("test1_md1.png",native=FALSE,info=TRUE)
attr(img2, "info")
```

I can open the new png file, it looks just like the old one.  However, the comment block is not filled.  As you can see, the data is written in the file, but neither gimp nor preview can read it.  Is there a way to write the metadata in the comment block so that preview and gimp can read it correctly?

Thank you

**update:** ok, png::writePNG does actually write into the tEXt block, however neither gimp nor preview read the text block. I wrote a simple java program that reads the blocks.

```
    IHDR null javax.imageio.metadata.IIONamedNodeMap@133314b
      width = 2580   height = 1800   bitDepth = 8   colorType = RGBAlpha   compressionMethod = deflate   filterMethod = adaptive   interlaceMethod = none 
    tEXt null javax.imageio.metadata.IIONamedNodeMap@b1bc7ed

        tEXtEntry null javax.imageio.metadata.IIONamedNodeMap@7cd84586
          keyword = date   value = Tue Dec  4 12:55:45 2018 
        tEXtEntry null javax.imageio.metadata.IIONamedNodeMap@30dae81
      keyword = machine.nodename   value = mycomputer.xyz.org
```

Is there a separate comment block somewhere?  That is the block I want to write to.

**update 2:** It appears that gimp/preview read the iTXt block.  So the question becomes can I write to the iTXt block from R.

Comment: PNG files do not have exif data. They have text blocks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)

Comment: You may want to read up on exiv2 before you snark at contributors. good luck getting an answer.